# Android Serializable Passing Data And Returning Changed Data

Tags: java, android

My Questions is as follow, I have a hashmap that I have Initialized in the main activity, my object class does implement seriliazable. My issue is that I can pass the object to another activity and read the values of the original hasmap, but when I add a new value to the hashmap in the new activity , it does not actually change the original hashmap when the activity ends.

This is How Im passing to the other activity

```
            HashMap<String,Book> detail1 = new HashMap<String,Book>;
            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlaceHold.class);
            bundle.putSerializable("hashMap",detail1);
            i2.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i2);
```

This is How the other activity uses the passed values

```
            HashMap<String,Book> hashMap = HashMap<String,Book>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
            hashMap.put(bookIsbn,new Book(bookTitle,bookIsbn,bookFee,bookAuthor));
            finish();
```

My Issue is that the added book does not appear when I pass the hashamp to teh other class. Only the default values that I set on MainActivity oncreate exists.

Answer (score 0):

The hashmap that you send to the second Activity is not the first Activity's hashmap, it's a serialized version of it.

You should navigate from the first Activity to the second with startActivityForResult instead of startActivity, and return the updated hashmap from the second Activity with setResult

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't sure what to use. Researched setActivityForResult and It worked.:)